# PHPでのAjaxによる連携リストボックスを作る上で

Tags: php, ajax

JavaScript・PHP双方手を出して大変間もないものです。標題の件を学ぶため、こちらの記事を参考に挑戦中です。
https://qiita.com/hibriiiiidge/items/0ad0eb9de7275b2f0110記事にある構成どおり、index.phpとselect.phpを作りました。社内DBへ接続する上で、実在する2テーブルからデータを取得するようには一部コードを置き換えさせて頂いています。
現在はindex.phpの一つ目=親リストボックスの表示まで成功しています。
こちらからアイテムを選択しても子リストボックスの中身が現れてこない、という状態で悩んでいます。

【そもそもの質問】
1：select.phpは、index.phpと同じフォルダに収めていく想定でこの記事は掲載されているのでしょうか？どこかにおくべき場所があるのか、もしくはincludeさせるべきものでしょうか？

2:select.phpへアクセスされているのか否かを知る術はありますか？現況子リストボックスの反応が見えないので．．．
ちなみに、select.php頭は現況以下になっています．．．

    print "ようこそＰＨＰへ";

但しindex.php上で親リストボックスからアイテムを選択しようと、「ようこそＰＨＰへ！」は現れません。直接select.phpにアクセスした場合には、この文言が画面に現れます。（当然かな？）

xamppで一連を取得しましたが、phpのログファイルは現況未設定の様です。
select.phpの中に記載されたERRORキャッチ時の$e->getMessage()なども一体　どこに現れるのだろうか？と考えています。

一先ず、状況を進展させるため、select.phpへアクセスされているのか否かを知りたいと考えてます。
まとまりのない問い合わせとなりましたが、ご支援をよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: xamppをお使いとのことですが、apacheのログファイルは確認できる環境でしょうか？

Comment: keitaro_so様　apacheはアクセスログとエラーログ双方確認できます。PHP Notice:  Undefined index: maker_no in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SharpNinth\\select.php on line 19, referer: http://localhost/SharpNinth/index.php
という記述がエラーログにみあたります。

Comment: PHP Notice: Undefined index: maker_noとエラーを吐いているのでパラメータmaker_noが何らかの原因で送信されてない（$maker_no = $_POST['maker_no']のところでエラー）かと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1:select.phpは、index.phpと同じフォルダに....

urlの指定がファイル名だけなのでindex.phpと同じフォルダに置きます。

```
$.ajax({
            url: "select.php",
            type: "POST",
```

> 2:select.phpへアクセスされているのか否かを知る術はありますか？

アクセスログか、ブラウザーの開発ツールで確認できると思います。
select.phpに関連するエラーを吐いているのでアクセス出来ていますね。

追記、リンク先のソースを見直したら
          maker_id: maker_val　は、"maker_no": maker_val ではないでしょうか　以下の部分です。
    (または、select.phpの　$_POST['maker_no']　を　$_POST['maker_id']に直す。)

```
  //maker_val値 を select.php へ渡す
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      maker_id: maker_val
    }
  })
```

答えてなかったので

> exit('データベース接続失敗'.$e->getMessage());　どこに

exitは、指定された文字列（データ）を表示(出力)して終了します。
さらに、phpで何らかのエラーが発生した場合、エラーが出力される設定になっていると
エラー内容も表示(出力)されます。

因みに、print_r($_POST);　とselect.phpの先頭にデバッグで入れると、送信されてきた全postパラメータが文字列表示（出力）されます。(getパラメータを見たいなら　print_r($_GET); です)

更に追記、コメントでは見づらいのでここに、以下をtest.phpなどのファイルにしてテストサーバなどに置いてブラウザーからアクセス（実行）して見ましょう。文章やエラー、実行結果などが表示されるでしょう、つまり、特に指定しなければ要求元に結果（内容）を返します。

```
PHP（ピー・エイチ・ピー）は "The PHP Development Team" によってコミュニティベースで開発されているオープンソースの汎用プログラミング言語であり、<br>特にサーバーサイドで動的なウェブページ作成するための機能を多く備える。 名称の PHP は再帰的頭字語である "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor" を意味[1][2]し、「PHPはHTMLのプリプロセッサである」とPHP自身を再帰的に説明している。
<?php
// エラー出力しない設定　php.iniでも設定できる
//ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

// エラー出力する設定
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
$aaaa = $_POST['aaaa'];



$array = array(array('a1'=>'data-a1'),array('a2'=>'data-a2'));

echo '<br>'.json_encode($array);

exit('<br>test');
```

Comment: 皆様ありがとうございます。
select.phpへのアクセスはなされている、との見解を頂き、一先ず安心しました。
select.php内の$_POST['maker_no']の取得に失敗している、と認識し、もとになっているindex.phpのajaxを呼ぶ直前で、メッセージボックスを表示するようにしてみました。（以下の如く。改行されて表示されない場合申し訳ないです）

$(function(){
    //selectタグ（親） が変更された場合
    $('[name=car_maker]').on('change', function(){
    var maker_val = $(this).val();
    // ***これ************ //
    alert(maker_val);
　　　// *************** //

　　　//maker_val値 を select.php へ渡す
　　　$.ajax({
　　　　　　　　url: "select.php",
　　　　　　　　type: "POST",
　　　　　　　　dataType: 'json',
　　　　　　　　data: {
　　　　　　　　maker_id: maker_val
　　　　}
})

Comment: すみません、伝え忘れました。このalertから選択した親リストボックスの内容は正常に表示されます

Comment: 追記しました。（link先サンプル、送信している所のpostパラメータ名が違っているような）

Comment: yyz様　バッチリです、無事連携されるようになりました。ご丁寧にリンク元のソースを確認頂きまして誠にありがとうございました。　ちなみにもし差支えなければ今後のために教えてください。「exitは、指定された文字列（データ）を表示(出力)して終了します。
さらに、phpで何らかのエラーが発生した場合、エラーが出力される設定になっていると
 エラー内容も表示(出力)されます。」これは実行中のブラウザ画面に現れるのか、何かのログか？

Comment: 実行中のブラウザ画面に出力されます。　更に追記しました。コメントでは見づらいので

Comment: yyz様　何から何まですみません。取り急ぎ丁寧な対応にお礼申し上げます。今晩試してみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: yyz様　test.php確認させて頂きました。役に立つ情報をありがとうございます。エラーを出力する設定、というものがあることも初めて知りました。iniで予めOnになっていることも確認致しました。実はそのことを確認した経緯はselect.phpの頭に仰られるように、print_r($_POST);　を入れても画面に何も現れなかったので．．．気になりまして。"デバッグで入れると"って、別に普通に挿入するだけで良いのですよね？？　また気が向いたら返事を頂けましたら幸いです。